# How to run a table from a database and create an object with each field of it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a table from which I want to take all fields and convert them in an object, I want to pass from a data to another instead of just show the first one.

This code makes the query and it's supposed to take ALL the table fields.

```
public static DataTable Search()
{
    DataTable db = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        NpgsqlConnection connection;
        connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=root;Database=test;");
        connection.Open();
        string consultation = "SELECT boxnum, partnum, quantity, date, nivel, row, deep FROM market ma INNER JOIN connection cn ON ma.boxnumm = cn.boxnum;";
        NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand(consultation, connection);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter adap = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(com);
        adap.Fill(db);
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    return db;
}
```

Then in a timer I try to start the object and reload the object from the database, but it just shows the first data and then it creates infinite objects with it.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = getTable.search();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
        partnum = Convert.ToString(row["partnum"]);
        quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row["quantity"]);
        deep = Convert.ToInt32(row["deep"]);
        row = Convert.ToInt32(row["row"]);
        boxnum = Convert.ToInt32(row["boxnum"]);
        aux = Convert.ToDateTime(row["date"]);
        boxs.Add(new Box(partnum,quantity,deep,aux,row,boxnum));
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

I want to check the table and create an object from each field of it, until now, my code check the table and create the object but it's creating a new one over the old each second.

Comment: The debugger is great at helping you find these, and training your brain not to make them.  `dt.Rows[0]` is the first row only.  Its not clear where they are going 9not into any object), so row 2 is going to overwrite those variable values.  might also want to look into ORMs

Comment: You need to run a loop, going through every row in the table and making a new object, then add that new object to the list